# Get list of values from one column based on values of multiple columns

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements

My data:

```
 Focal NrN Distance  DSS
 A      Z        1    1
 A      Z        2    2
 A      Z        2    3
 A      Y        3    3
```

I want to get a list of DSS values when value in Focal column is A and value in NrN is Z. The result should be values 1, 2 and 3 from the DSS column.

I've tried this:

```
FOC_NrN <- data$Focal=="A" & data$NrN== "Z"
table(data$DSS,FOC_NrN)



FOC_NrN
    FALSE TRUE
  1     0    1
  2     0    1
  3     1    1
  4     1    0
  5     1    0
  6     1    0
  7     1    0
  8     1    0
```

But I can't  get a list of three DSS values in the TRUE column - that's all I want so that it can be applied to other scripts and loop it

Comment: Do you need `data$DSS[FOC_NrN]`

Comment: @akrun, That's what I needed but without the ! - so simple - what a n00b. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to subset the "DSS" column

```
data$DSS[FOC_NrN]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: How would I then count that. So answer is 3? sum(data$DSS[FOC_NrN]) gives me 6.

Comment: @Bonono Just use `length` i.e. `length(data$DSS[FOC_NrN])`